# Pass context to a ajax call in a callback

Tags: javascript, ajax, django

I know there are plenty of questions and answers about this, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) for example, but I cant get it to work in my specific situation. I am trying to pass variables to a view with an ajax call, the start and end dates.

```
    $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    opens: 'left'
}, function(start, end, label) {
    console.log("A new date selection was made: " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/courses/pageviewsbydate/",
        data: {
            'start_date' : start,
            'end_date' : end,
            'csrfmiddlewaretoken' : $("input[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val()
        },
        success: GA_pagesviewsSuccess.bind(this),
        dataType: 'html'
    });
    console.log("got here");
});
```

Comment: You should be able to pass start and end as extra parameters in `GA_pagesviewsSuccess.bind(this, start, end)`

Comment: the TypeError is being thrown by moment.min.js,  which datrangepicker is using, I dont know why an ajax call would cause the error though.

Comment: You didn't ask about a typeerror in your question.